# mongoDB: Querying for documents that may have some specifics options

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm quite new to mongodb and there is one thing I can't solve right now:
Let's pretend, you have the following document structure:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("some object id"),
name: "valueName",
options: [
    {idOption: "optionId", name: "optionName"},
    {idOption: "optionId", name: "optionName"}
]
}
```

And each document can have multiples options that are already classified.

I'm trying to get all the documents in the collection that have, at least one, of the multiples options that I pass for the query.

I was trying with the operator `$elemMatch` something like this:

```
db.collectioName.find({"options.name": { $elemMatch: {"optName1","optName2"}}})
```

but it never show me the matches documents.

Can someone help and show me, what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a collection which contains the following documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a023b8d027b5bd06add627a"),
    "name" : "valueName",
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "idOption" : "optionId",
            "name" : "optName1"
        }, 
        {
            "idOption" : "optionId",
            "name" : "optName2"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a023b9e027b5bd06add627d"),
    "name" : "valueName",
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "idOption" : "optionId",
            "name" : "optName3"
        }, 
        {
            "idOption" : "optionId",
            "name" : "optName4"
        }
    ]
}
```

This query ...

```
db.collection.find({"options": { $elemMatch: {"name": {"$in": ["optName1"]}}}})
```

.. will return the first document only.

While, this query ...

```
db.collection.find({"options": { $elemMatch: {"name": {"$in": ["optName1", "optName3"]}}}})
```

...will return both documents.

The second example (I think) meeets this requirement:

> I'm trying to get all the documents in the collection that have, at least one, of the multiples options that I pass for the query.

Comment: Or actually simply `.find({ "options.name": { "$in": ["optName1", "optName3"] } })` since `$elemMatch` is **only** required where "multiple conditions" are required of the "same array element". The query here only needs to make "either" value "somewhere" in the array. See [Specify Multiple Conditions for Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-of-documents) which explains the difference.